# How to hide the first line in ScintillaNET?

Tags: c#, scintilla

Having a ScintillaNET control, I can hide line 2

```
scintilla.Text = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";
scintilla.HideLines(1,1);
```

or line 2 and 3

```
scintilla.Text = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";
scintilla.HideLines(1,2);
```

but nothing that would start at line 1 (index 0)

```
scintilla.Text = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";
scintilla.HideLines(0,2);
```

How can I hide the first line of text in ScintillaNET?

Line 1 of my file format is written by the editor and shall never be edited by the user, so I'd like it not to be shown at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `HideLines` is the right tool for the job, since it is part of Scintilla's [folding API](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#Folding). The [styling API](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#StyleDefinition) would probably be more appropriate.

However, I doubt whether any API *on its own* can really prevent hidden text being edited by the user. For example, it would require aditional handling to stop the user deleting a block of text that happened to include a hidden portion (this is certainly true for the folding APIs, anyway).

For your particular case, though, isn't there a much simpler solution? Why not just remove the first line of the text before loading it into the editor (and add it back before saving)?